# onBindViewHolder is giving me a null ArrayList because the data hasn't finished loading from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For RecyclerView my onBindViewHolder is using setText from an ArrayList that I load data in, from firebase.
However for the first onBindViewHolder call, it's giving me a null ArrayList because the data hasn't finished loading. (2nd, 3rd ... etc get the values in time)
How do I call onBindViewHolder, after my ArrayList has finished retrieving all the data?

Answer (score 0):

Try to load the data in before seting the adapter. In the adapter, pass the data through the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

try to setAdapter after loading all data in List.
and in getItemCount do this

```
 @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (list == null)
            return 0;
        return list.size();
    }
```

this is for is your list is null it will return 0 means onBindViewHolder will not get call and its not null then it will return size of list at that time your onBindViewHolder will get called